# Expextation of products of Standard Brownian Motion

Tags: brownian-motion

$B_{i} $ is a standard Brownian motion.
$$E[\prod_{i=1}^3 B_{i}]$$

I know how to find $E[B_{1}B_{2}]$, but how do I find the expectation of this one?

$E[B_{1}(B_{2}-B_{1}+B_{1})(B_{3}-B{2}+B_{2})]=E[B_{1}(B_{2}-B_{1})(B_{3}-B_{2})+B_{1}B_{2}(B_{2}-B_{1})+B_{1}^2B_{2}+B_{1}^2(B_{3}-B_{2})]=E[B_{1}B_{2}^2]+E[B_{1}^2(B_{3}-B_{2})]$

This is my workings so far.

Comment: It is an odd variable

Answer (score 1):

We write $\Delta_{ij}$ for the increment $B_j-B_i$, $j>i$, and have
soon products of only increments:
$$
\begin{aligned}
B_3 &= (B_1-B_0) + (B_2-B_1)+ (B_3-B_2)\\
    &= \Delta_{01}+\Delta_{12}+\Delta_{23}\ ,\\
B_2 &= (B_1-B_0) + (B_2-B_1)\\
    &= \Delta_{01}+\Delta_{12}\ ,\\
B_1 &= (B_1-B_0)\\
    &= \Delta_{01}\ .\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{This implies:}\\[3mm]
\Bbb E[\ B_3B_2B_1\ ]
&=
\Bbb E\left[\ 
\Big(\ \Delta_{01}+\Delta_{12}+\Delta_{23}\Big)
\Big(\ \Delta_{01}+\Delta_{12}\Big)
\Delta_{01}
 \ \right]
\\
&=
\Bbb E\left[\ 
\Big(\ \Delta_{01}+\Delta_{12}+\Delta_{23}\Big)
\Big(\ \Delta_{01}^2+\Delta_{12}\Delta_{01}\Big)
 \ \right]
\\[3mm]
&=
\Bbb E\left[\ 
\Delta_{01}^3+\Delta_{01}^2\Delta_{12}+\Delta_{01}^2\Delta_{23}
 \ \right]
\\
&\qquad\qquad
+
\Bbb E\left[\ 
\Delta_{01}^2\Delta_{12}+\Delta_{01}\Delta_{12}^2
+\Delta_{01}\Delta_{12}\Delta_{23}
 \ \right]
\\[3mm]
&=
\Bbb E\left[\Delta_{01}^3\right]
+
\Bbb E\left[\Delta_{01}^2\Delta_{12}\right]
+
\Bbb E\left[\Delta_{01}^2\Delta_{23}\right]
\\
&\qquad\qquad
+
\Bbb E\left[ \Delta_{01}^2\Delta_{12}\right]
+
\Bbb E\left[\Delta_{01}\Delta_{12}^2\right]
+
\Bbb E\left[\Delta_{01}\Delta_{12}\Delta_{23}\right]
\\[3mm]
&=
\Bbb E\left[\Delta_{01}^3\right]
+
\Bbb E\left[\Delta_{01}^2\right]\; \Bbb E\left[\Delta_{12}\right]
+
\Bbb E\left[\Delta_{01}^2\right]\; \Bbb E\left[\Delta_{23}\right]
\\
&\qquad\qquad
+
\Bbb E\left[ \Delta_{01}^2\right]\; \Bbb E\left[\Delta_{12}\right]
+
\Bbb E\left[\Delta_{01}\right]\; \Bbb E\left[\Delta_{12}^2\right]
+
\Bbb E\left[\Delta_{01}\right]\; \Bbb E\left[\Delta_{12}\right]\; \Bbb E\left[\Delta_{23}\right]
\\[3mm]
\end{aligned}
$$
Among the many products some are vanishing... i hope it is clear now how to proceed...

Answer (score 1):

$$E(B_1B_2B_3)=E[E(B_1B_2B_3|B_1,B_2)]$$ $$=EB_1B_2E(B_3|B_1,B_2)$$ and $$E(B_3|B_1,B_2)$$ $$=E(B_3-B_2|B_1,B_2)+E(B_2|B_1,B_2)=B_2.$$ Hence, $E(B_1B_2B_3)=EB_1B_2^{2}$. Now write $B_2$ as $(B_2-B_1) +B_1$. Can you finish?

Comment: That's the thing, I'm stuck at $E[B_{1}B_{2}^2]$

Comment: Never mind, I got it. Now I just have to figure out the third moment of SBM

Comment: $EB_1^{3}=0$ by symmetry of the distrbution of $B_1$.  @CJC.10